# How to install Kile on Debian KDE 7.3 32 bit?

Tags: kde, debian, latex, kile

For the past week or so, I'm trying to install **Kile** in Debian 7.3 kde desktop *after* installing TexLive 2013 from a CTAN mirror (downloading the installer in a home directory, decompressing it in `install-tl-20140123` and launching the `/.install-tl`). I had installed `perl-tk` but apparently it doesn't work when called by `/.install-tl` so I had to make-do with the text interface. I installed a small version of TeXLive (13 or so packages for a tot of ~730MB). Now, when I go to install Kile from Synaptick Package Manager I get many packages automatically ticked for installation including `texlive-common`,`texlive-base`, `luatex`. From what I've read on the Internet, I need to fool the system into believing it already has those packages by creating so-called dummy packages so the system only installs Kile. Is there someone who has a **correct** and easy guide on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

See [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu: Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian](http://tug.org/texlive/debian.html).If that doesn't work for you, [TeX - LateX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place to ask than here.